# unit testing custom knockoutjs binding

Tags: unit-testing, knockout.js

How can I unit test this knockoutjs binding where I call a certain function 'myValueAccessor' when the element is swiped on my touchpad?

I am also unsure what the unit should or is able to test at all here.

It would be ok for the first time to assert wether myValueAccessor is called.

But how can I trigger/imitate or should I say mock... the swiperight event?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tap = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();    

        var hammertime1 = Hammer(element).on("swiperight", function (event) {
            $(element).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                value();
            });
        });
    }
};

 self.myValueAccessor = function () {
    location.href = 'set a new url'
};
```

**UPDATE**

I have put here my unit test with mocha.js

I can outcomment the 'value()' in the binding but still the test succeeded thats odd.

Is it not correct to put this (as a test):

```
function (element,args) {
                    alert('assertion here');
                }
```

as a 3rd parameter into the ko.test function?

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.tap = {
                    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
                        var value = valueAccessor();

                        var hammertime1 = $(element).on("swiperight", function (event) {
                            $(element).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                //value();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };

                // Subscribe the swiperight event to the jquery on function
                $.fn.on = function (event, callback) {
                    if (event === "swiperight") {
                        callback();
                    }
                };

                // Subscribe the fadeOut event to the jquery fadeOut function
                $.fn.fadeOut = function (speed, callback) {
                    callback();
                };


                ko.test("div", {
                    tap: function () {
                        assert.ok(true, "It should call the accessor");
                    }
                }, function () {
                });
```

UPDATE:

custom.bindings.js:

```
define(['knockout','hammer'], function (ko,Hammer) {
    return function Bindings() {

        ko.bindingHandlers.tap = {
            'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();

                var hammertime1 = Hammer(element).on("swiperight", function (event) {
                    $(element).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                        value();
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    };
});
```

unittest.js:

how can I connect this code to knockout in my test?

**UPDATE**

The Bindings is injected via require.js from my bindings.js file:

```
describe("When swiping left or right", function () {
            it("then the accessor function should be called", function () {

                ko.bindingHandlers.tap = new Bindings();

                Hammer.Instance.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
                    if (event === "swiperight") {
                        callback();
                    }
                };

                $.fn.fadeOut = function (speed, callback) {
                    callback();
                };
                var accessorCalled = false;
                ko.test("div", {
                    tap: function () {
                        accessorCalled = true;
                    }
                }, function () {
                    assert.ok(accessorCalled, "It should call the accessor");
                });

            });
        });
```

bindings.js

```
define(['knockout','hammer'], function (ko,Hammer) {
    return function () {

        return {
            'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();

                var hammertime1 = Hammer(element).on("swiperight", function (event) {
                    $(element).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                        value();
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    };
});
```

myviewmodel.js

```
...

ko.bindingHandlers.tap = new Bindings();

...
```

Comment: THe third argyment to my ko.test is used when you want to assert the DOM element was updated correctly bv the binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check my binding collection for how to test 
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings/tree/master/test

This is my function that all my tests using

```
ko.test = function (tag, binding, test) {
    var element = $("<" + tag + "/>");
    element.appendTo("body");
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element[0], binding);
    var args = {
        clean: function () {
            element.remove();
        }
    };
    test(element, args);

    if (!args.async) {
        args.clean();
    }
};
```

edit: Sorry forgot mocking, you just do

```
$.fn.on = function() {
}
```

I do not know what exact logic you want to test in that code since there hardly is any, but something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/Akqur/

**edit:** 
May you get confused where i hook up your binding? Its done here

```
{ 
   tap: function() {
      ok(true, "It should call the accessor");
   }
}
```

I tell ko to hook up a "tap" binding and instead of hooking in up to a observable I use a mocking function, when your custom bindnig calls `value()` from the fadeout function the test assert will fire

**edit:** 
Maybe this approuch makes more sense to you?
http://jsfiddle.net/Akqur/5/
Note that it only works if your code is executed synchronous

**edit:** 
Here i use the third argument of ko.test
http://jsfiddle.net/Akqur/8/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how this could would help in my special case? else you could throw this code against every knockout web test question it could always be helpful somehow...

Comment: twice you call the callback(); function in fadeOut and on of jquery. But where is that callback() defined? I know you are passing it as function parameter but where does it originally come from?

Comment: You call them in your binding.

Comment: In your ko.test function the 3rd parameter is the function to test? what does that mean. Its declared like that function () { } This seems to be an empty function, so what is the purpose of that?

Comment: My tap binding is inside a viewmodel. I do not understand how you would get this binding to use it in the unit test?

Comment: I do not understand why I can make your test fail in jsfiddle, but when I try to integrate your code into mocha.js the assertion is always true... I guess I am missing some understanding here in javascript mocking/testing which I am not used to...

Comment: Qunit (Testing framework i use in my fiddle) fails if no assertion was called, maybe thats your problem? Does Mocha.js also fail tests were no assertion was called? Also see my edit

Comment: No Mocha does not fail if there is no assertion. Just tested it.

Comment: Ok thanks the latest approach works. That means the assertion is green/red when I remove the ko.bindingHandlers.tap = { .. } code which should be replaced by my real code because I do not want to test a snippet, right? My tap binding is inside a VM which is newed up in the unit test but still the test fails. My ViewModel has just the snippet inside thats it so newing up the vm instance already adds the binding to ko, but why is it not used or does not work in the same way the snippet works?

Comment: Your vm's and your custom bindings should be tested separate, the whole point of KO is to decouple the view (Html) and the view logic (ViewModel).

Comment: OK. BUT should I really copy my custom binding out of my production viewmodel into my unit test? What if the production custom binding is changed then my unit test will never fail! I do not understand how that can be the right way? :)

Comment: Move your custom bindings to a knockout.custom.bindings.js file and your viewmodel to a ViewModelName.js file. Write tests for both but in separate tests js files. You will never get a soid code base if you mix bindings and viewmodels

Comment: Why write tests for both in separate tests.js file? Because you want to have the binding tests separate? Am just curious. And I assume that I have to inject the knockout.custom.bindings.js with requirejs into my viewmodel.js and into my bindingstest.js as dependency?

Comment: Your viewmodel does not have dependencies to your custom bindings, your view does. If not, then you are designing it wrong. Its one of KOs main tasks to glue together your view logic with your view.

Comment: Now I understood that I have to see a custom binding as a ko extension not as a viewmodel function... or sth belonging to a viewmodel.

Comment: I am injecting now the custom bindings from my bindings.js file but it does not behave like I would directly declare the binding in the unit test. How can I correct that? I have updated my init question with code!

Comment: I have also seen that you have removed my hammer.js dependency in the custom binding that way I can not reuse the binding in the unit test and real code. Of course with hammer inside the binding test would be no unit test...

Comment: Why have you removed that? With that removal the unit test sample is of no help for me. Maybe I should not have mentioned the word "unit test" ? Maybe it was irritating to you and therefore you removed the hammer dependency?

Comment: I didn't have that dependency so hanged it to $ since it has a on event function too. Forgot to mention that

Comment: Yes but that was essential ;P I guess I have to bother now my colleague... or give up.

Comment: ok now I understand you mock the hammer. Works here. Thanks. Really you should use all this code and make a tutorial out of it when you have a blog running? Many would love that!

Comment: What I have done now to assign the custom binding in my unit test and to have the same structure in my viewmodel is updated in my init question. If you have a better idea please let me know. I say this because I do not like that I have to return the init code as object literial and the ko.bindingHandlers.tap is declared in my unit test and in my viewmodel. I would like to also inject the 'ko.bindingHandlers.tap = ' into my unit test and viewmodel.